# Jmeter - matchNr returning null

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I am storing a variable using vars.put() in JMeter and when i try to use _matchNr, it is returning null. Upon logging the variable in the same file where i am calling _matchNr, it showed correct output (which should meant that variable is not null in itself). So is there a reason, why matchNr is giving null output?

```
log.info("this is transaction" + "${transactionAmountResp}"); 
log.info("this is transaction_match" + 
vars.get("transactionAmountResp_matchNr")); 
int number = Integer.parseInt("${transactionAmountResp_matchNr}");
```

I am using this in Beanshell Assertion to check whether transactionAmountResp matches with some other already set variable.

Comment: show exactly what you tried

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `${}` syntax inside Beanshell/JSR233 script, use `vars.get`

```
log.info("this is transaction" + vars.get("transactionAmountResp")); 

int number = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("transactionAmountResp_matchNr"));
```

Comment: Okay, but even ${} is giving proper output. But vars.get("transactionAmountResp_matchNr") is giving me null. My question was, if there exists a variable, why would matchNr return null? is there a work-around this?

Comment: @V.Bhanderi `matchNr` variable is added **only** if you are getting variable using regular expression, you won't have  `transactionAmountResp_matchNr` variable if you just put a `transactionAmountResp` variable in script

Comment: Okay, so this is the code flow. I am getting message via Queue (using IBM MQ). I am saving this message in a variable,and then in a beanshell post-processor, perform some string operations on it, and save the data retrieved in a variable named 'transactionAmountResp'. Now i want to use the variable, 'transactionAmountResp_matchNr' in a beanshell assertion. 

Sorry for the trouble, I am kind of a beginner in Jmeter.

Comment: @V.Bhanderi you don't automatically have matchNr variable, what value you expect it to hold?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
2. [Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), use code-based equivalents instead
3. You can use normal [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) for comparing 2 JMeter Variables:

   [image]
4. You can double check JMeter Variables or Properties values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/), if the variable is not there it's absolutely expected that you will get `null` trying to read its value